# how to run validation on text fields

Tags: android, lost-focus, textedit

The goal here is to validate each field as the user enters contact information AND eventually to apply auto-format (capitalization, spelling, etc) to each field.

I have this nearly working using the following code, but it is based on a keypress callback and what I really want to trigger on is a "loss of focus" for each text field.  Any ideas?

```
public TextFormValidationCallback (CustomerFormActivity faja, String editTextName, Context context, EditText textField, 
                                   Button button, int rule) {
    this.button = button;
    this.textField = textField;
    this.context = context;
    this.ruleResourceId = rule;
    this.editTextName = editTextName;
    this.faja = faja;
    this.res = context.getResources();
}

public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event != null) {

        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            // Perform action on key press
            Log.i("TextFormValidation",
                    "TextFormValidation callback activated!");
            if (validateTextFieldNotNullData(this.textField)
                    && (validateTextFieldFormat(this.textField,
                            ruleResourceId))) {
                faja.setFieldValidationArray(getHeadingIndex(editTextName),
                        true);
                if (faja.sumFieldValidations()) {
                    button.setClickable(true);
                    button.setText(R.string.addCustomer);
                }
            } else {
                button.setText(R.string.next);
                button.setClickable(false);
            }
            return true;
        }
    } else {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: try to SetFocus() on any other control in your click event.

Comment: Have you tried View.setOnFocusChangeListener()?

Answer (score 0):

Could this maybe be what you're looking for?
[TextView.onWindowFocusChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29)

Comment: I don't think so (from reading the docs), but I will write a separate callback to make sure.

Comment: There is no listener that I can find for onWindowFocusChanged() and loosing focus is not an editorAction.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it would not let me post this yesterday, but I figured it out.  To save everyone else from this facepalm moment, I will post the fixed code here.

```
public class TextFormValidationCallback  implements OnFocusChangeListener {

private Button button;
private EditText textField;
private Integer ruleResourceId;
private Resources res;
private Context context;
private String editTextName;
private CustomerFormActivity faja;

public TextFormValidationCallback (CustomerFormActivity faja, String editTextName, Context context, EditText textField, 
                                   Button button) {
    this.button = button;
    this.textField = textField;
    this.context = context;
    this.editTextName = editTextName;
    this.res = context.getResources();
    this.ruleResourceId = R.string.validates_everything;
    this.faja = faja;
}

public TextFormValidationCallback (CustomerFormActivity faja, String editTextName, Context context, EditText textField, 
                                   Button button, int rule) {
    this.button = button;
    this.textField = textField;
    this.context = context;
    this.ruleResourceId = rule;
    this.editTextName = editTextName;
    this.faja = faja;
    this.res = context.getResources();
}

public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    Log.i("TextFormValidation", "TextFormValidation callback activated!");
    if (! hasFocus) {
        if (validateTextFieldNotNullData(this.textField)) {
           if (validateTextFieldvsFormat(this.textField, ruleResourceId)) {
                faja.setFieldValidationArray(getHeadingIndex(editTextName), true);
           }
        }
        if (faja.sumFieldValidations()) {
            button.setClickable(true);
            button.setText(R.string.addCustomer);
        }
        else {
            button.setText(R.string.next);
            button.setClickable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

}